# issues connecting to postgres using pg client

Tags: postgresql

Trying to connect to postgres using the [pg client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) (following [these](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/connect-to-postgresql-using-javascript/) instructions).

Here is my connection string `var connectionString = "postgres://postgres:pass@localhost/ip:5432/chat";`

Here's the error I'm getting trying to connect:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): error: database "ip:5432/twitchchat" does not exist`

However, when I run `pg_isready` I get the response `/tmp:5432 - accepting connections` Which I read as telling me postgres is running on port 5432.

The database is very definitely existing.

Here's the simple connection code:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = 
"postgres://postgres:pass@localhost/ip:5432/chat";

var connection = new pg.Client(connectionString);

connection.connect();
```

What's happening here? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string is malformed:

Change it to:

```
`"postgres://postgres:pass@localhost:5432/chat"`
```

The correct format is:

```
postgresql://[user]:[password]@[address]:[port]/[dbname]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it with the following:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const connection = new Client({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'chat',
  password: 'pass',
  port: 5432,
});

connection.connect();
```